# .htaccess RewriteRule: Rewriting an URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

is there any way to change www.domain.com/index.php?value=htaccessnoob to www.domain.com/htaccessnoob with rewrite conditions and rulez?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: YOu can use any regular expression in rewrite so technically you could add something like this:

regex: (\?|&)[a-zA-Z]*=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)
replacement: /$2

this turn: www.domain.com/index.php?value=htaccessnoob&id=lalala
into: www.domain.com/index.php/htaccessnoob/lalala

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me with my special case - i don't have any idea how to solve this and I guess I'm not a fan of regular expressions :)

Comment: Try o add this rewrite rule:
RewriteRule (\?|&)[a-zA-Z]=([a-zA-Z0-9]) /$2

I dont have any place to test it on atm.. But this should work. It should put all values in order you put them in your url. So this should work for your url or any other url.

if you don't want a generic way but something only for your pattern you can use:
RewriteRule \?value=([a-zA-Z0-9]*) /$1 instead

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?value=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+) /index.php?value=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```